# How to specify an autoregressive correlation structure in a linear model when the data has multiple observations at each time step?

Tags: r, regression, time-series, arima, autocorrelation

I want to fit a multiple regression model that accounts for temporally-correlated errors (i.e., some sort of autoregressive correlation structure, like those provided by ARMA or ARIMA models). However, the problem I have is that my data set isn't a simple continuous time series (i.e., one that has only one data point at every single time step). In my data set, each time step may contain one, several or no data points.

Because of this, I cannot use standard autoregressive correlation structures, such as those provided by `corAR1()` or `corARMA()` in R, or the function `auto.arima()` with `xreg` regression.

It might help to be more specific about my data set. I am analysing estimates of biological diversity through geological time (numbers of species, estimated using the fossil record) for roughly equally-sized geographic regions. I am using multiple regression to understand the role of various environmental variables on diversity.

Time points actually correspond to so-called "time bins"—lumped intervals of geological time with roughly equal durations (for example, the Late Cretaceous is one time bin). In some time bins, I have diversity estimates for several different geographic regions. In others, only one estimate is available, or even no estimates, if there are no known fossils. The identities/locations of geographic regions are not constant through time: they vary because the geographic distribution of fossil sites varies through time.

Is there any way to specify an autoregressive correlation structure for this kind of more complex data set? I'm happy to use whatever modelling approach is necessary.

I think it would be reasonable to treat time steps with multiple data points as representing multiple measurements from the same subject (planet Earth).

EDIT: The answer posted by user "HCQ" suggested that I a should fit a multilevel model with a random effect for geographic regions. This suggestion doesn't solve the problem, because geographic identities of data points are not constant through time (see revised question, above).

Comment: Do you mean there are more than one measurement at one time point for a single subject in your study?

Comment: No, not more than one measurement for a single subject (unless you count the Earth as a single subject). In fact, these are counts of species within geographic regions from across the globe through geological time. Through geological time, there may be time intervals when there are no geographic regions (no fossils known from which to count species), a single geographic region yielding species counts, or multiple regions. I'm ignoring spatial autocorrelation for now.

Comment: I assume that you are going to fit a two-level model, level 1 includes counts of spices along geological time in each region, level 2 includes different geographic regions that we measure the counts. Do I understand the question right?

Comment: Thus far I've only been fitting a simple linear model that doesn't identify regions per se: species_count ~ time + environmental_variable1 + environmental_variable2. For each value of time, there might be a single region/data point or multiple regions/datapoints. The identities of regions vary through time, too—I'm not tracking specific geographic regions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you wish to estimate a model of the following form:
$$y_{t,i}=\beta' x_t + \nu_t + \eta_{t,i},$$
where $t$ indexes time, $i$ indexes location and (e.g.):
$$\nu_t=\rho \nu_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t,$$
$$[\eta_{t,1},\dots,\eta_{t,N}]\sim N(0,\Sigma),$$
$$\varepsilon_{t}\sim N(0,\sigma_\varepsilon^2),$$
where:
$$\Sigma_{i,j}=\sigma_\eta^2 \exp{(-\gamma d_{i,j})},$$
and $d_{i,j}$ is (some measure of) the distance between locations $i$ and $j$.

I.e. you have multiple potentially noisy observations of the same unobserved underlying process (with spatially correlated noise).

(This can obviously be generalized to an arbitrary "ARIMA" type persistence structure.)

State space models such as this may be estimated with the [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter). Missing observations (i.e. not observing all locations in each time period) are no problem if estimating with the Kalman Filter.

There is a description of the available tools for state space modelling in R in the paper ["State Space Models in R" by Petris and Petrone](https://www.jstatsoft.org/htaccess.php?volume=41&type=i&issue=04&paper=true).

Comment: Thanks—I think this is a useful suggestion. However, I think that the best way to analyse my data would be to fit a correlation structure that simultaneously accounts for both temporal and spatial autocorrelation. State space models treat geographic regions within time bins purely as noisy observations of the same underlying process. This is true to some extent, but doesn't account for the fact that biodiversity varies systematically across the planet. Unfortunately, I don't think that methods for simultaneously modelling spatial and temporal autocorrelation exist!

Comment: Allowing for spatial correlation simultaneously is not that difficult. I have edited the answer to also incorporate spatial correlation. The model may still be estimated by the Kalman Filter, as it's still a linear state space model. Unfortunately, the richer structure means that it's more likely you have to write code yourself. But you can still rely on existing functions that will give you the likelihood of a linear state space model, via the Kalman filter. You just need to write a function that maps the parameter vector into the coefficients of the linear state space model.

Comment: One more thing: Don't forget that since the parameters of the linear state space model are now non-linear in the true parameters (namely $\gamma$), you will need a change of variables term in the likelihood. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Application_in_probability

Answer (score 1):

I have seen your dataset, I think your data structure has two levels as in the following figure: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R8cQFGk4Jhw1IHWam6Z2uhcFAZcTCF70.

I believe you should fit a multilevel model which gives geographic regions random effects to explain between-region variance, and I think it is improper to just ignore the variation among different regions which may lead to reduced statistical power.

If you change your mind to fit a multilevel model, then I think you can easily fit a hierarchical poisson regression model in `nlme()` with the covariance structure you need.

Comment: No, not keeping track of specific regions through time, just using separate species counts for whatever regions are known in each time bin (one region per df row):

`| region_id | time_bin | age_myr | species_count | env_var1 | env_var2 |`
`| ——-- | ——-- | ——-- | ——-- | ——-- | ——-- |`
`| bin1_region_A | bin1 | 1.5 | 10 | 4.5 | 10.2 |`
`| bin1_region_B | bin1 | 1.5 | 20 | 4.5 | 20.2 |`
`| bin1_region_C | bin1 | 1.5 | 8 | 42.5 | 30.2 |`
`| bin2_region_A | bin2 | 5.3 | 43 | 4.5 | 30.2 |`
`| bin3_region_A | bin3 | 8.7 | 22 | 3.5 | 80.2 |`
| bin3_region_B | bin3 | 8.7 | 3 | 4.5 | 20.2 |`

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to format a table in comments. Here is a [screenshot of the table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qkhawpkb5zx6jcy/Screen%20Shot%202019-06-07%20at%2012.51.44%20pm.png).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23213599)

Comment: Does your answer still hold true if you consider that the region in "bin1_region_A" has nothing at all to do with "bin2_region_A"? In other words, "region_A" does not indicate similar or identical geographic locations from one time bin to the next—it's purely a naming convention.

Comment: I 'm not familiar with geography at all. If this also involves changes of regions along time as you said, I think my suggestion is wrong.

Comment: It might be appropriate to treat the data as potentially having more than one measurement at each time point for a single subject (planet Earth). Do you have any suggestions for that scenario?

Comment: So you are dealing with a regression model with correlated errors, please refer to: http://stat565.cwick.co.nz/lectures/11-regression.pdf.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the approach detailed in those lecture slides only apply to time series data that consist of a single value per time step — gls and corARMA works for that simpler case, but not for my data.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter because generalized linear model allows correlated errors no matter whether the data is time-series.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94642/discussion-between-roger-and-hcq).